# How can I easily view and record a video input in Linux?

Tags: linux, recording, video-capture, lirc

I currently have my Wii plugged into a Linux box with a Hauppauge WinTV PVR-350.

To view the video input on my monitor I use VLC with `/dev/video0` as the input.

This works great, but I would like to be able to press the record button on the capture card's remote and have the Linux box start recording my Wii's output until I press the stop button.

I've fiddled around using `irexec` to just pipe the output of `/dev/video0` to a file, but this seems inelegant as a solution.

**Is there anything out there that makes it easy to view, and arbitrarily record, a video input using a lirc interface?**

The box currently has Ubuntu 9.04, but that should be irrelevant.

I've also posted this question on the [Ubuntu Community Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7970648#post7970648).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use irexec to kickoff mencoder, which can use a v4l input. You will have to use the tv:// url as the encode source and specify the v4l device with some options that can be found in the mencode/mplayer man page.

You should also be able to use it to kickoff VLC as an encoder as well (VLC can both run headless [minus a gui] and sports a fully featured encoder) from the commandline.

But for the easiest solution, I think you should look into a linux DVR app like MythTV, which should support all of this out of the box.

Comment: I'd like a solution somewhere between scripts and bloated DVR apps like MythTV, but thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I ended up going the scripted route by using irexec like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NVRec](http://nvrec.sourceforge.net/). Also check this list of applications: [Video for Linux resources](http://www.exploits.org/v4l/)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at [this page](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Use_Lirc).  Based on your comments to @Saavedro, however, it might be too 'scripty' for you.

It does allow you to exert full ir control and call whatever programs you want to map to different controls, but typing is definitely required.